# Reading a db again after re-opening the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am developing an app that's reading a db from parse.com with coordinates plotting out on a MapKit-map. Everything works fine but when a new pin is added manually by me on the web at parse.com, it doesn't show up when opening the app after pushing the home-button on my phone.

Where and how could I ask if the app has been shot down?

Hope I explained in an understandable way.

It could also be nice to have the app opening from scratch every time it is opened with the launch-image and so on. But I suppose that is not possible as one always has to close apps that are in the background by double-clicking on the phone.

Thankful for answers

Comment: in view did load call parse function and store it in db

Answer (score 0):

If by 'app has been shot down' you mean the app  moved to background after pressing the home button, then to know about this event you need to implement `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method in your appdelegate.m

These functions along with comments are created by xcode, when you start a new project.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"App Background");
    /* Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, 
    invalidate timers, and store enough application state information 
    to restore your application to its current state 
    in case it is terminated later.
    If your application supports background execution, 
    this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: 
    when the user quits.
    */
}
```

To know when the app was opened again, implement `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method in your appdelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"App Active");

    /* Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) 
    while the application was inactive. 
    If the application was previously in the background, 
    optionally refresh the user interface.
    */
}
```